# Switching the Binding Source of DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

In my view there is a DataGrid and its `ItemsSource` is bound to a Filelist from 3 different folders.

Is it possible to switch the binding source programatically?

E.g. for the first click `ItemsSource="{Binding FileList}`
and for the second click `ItemsSource="{Binding FileList1}`

Is this possible in the same DataGrid? I'm following MVVM and i use Prism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to change the data context on click or on some other action..
You said that you are using MVVM prism... here is a sample i have created to assist you..

In this sample my source(in your case it is datagrid) itemssource property will always binded to a property "Sourcelist" and on click i am re assigning the Sourcelist to diffrent list.. 
so on every click we are reassigning the sourcelist property which is binded to datagrid or list

```
class Viewmodel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Viewmodel()
        {
            ChangeDataSource = new DelegateCommand<object>(ChagneDataSource);
            Filelist1 = new FileListOne();
            FileList2 = new FileListTwo();
            Filelist1.Files = new List<string>();
            FileList2.Files = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Filelist1.Files.Add("FileListOne " + i);
                FileList2.Files.Add("FileListTwo " + i);
            }

            Sourcelist = Filelist1;
        }

        private object _sourcelist;

        public object Sourcelist
        {
            get
            {
                return _sourcelist;
            }
            set
            {
                _sourcelist = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Sourcelist");
            }
        }


        public ICommand ChangeDataSource { get; set; }

        public FileListOne Filelist1 { get; set; }

        public FileListTwo FileList2 { get; set; }

        private void ChagneDataSource(object seder)
        {
            if (Sourcelist.GetType() == typeof(FileListOne))
                Sourcelist = FileList2;
            else
                Sourcelist = Filelist1;
        }
    }

    class FileListOne
    {
        public List<string> Files { get; set; }
    }


    class FileListTwo
    {
        public List<string> Files { get; set; }
    }
```

XAML

```
<StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="listbox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Sourcelist.Files}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Command="{Binding ChangeDataSource}"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Good usage of MVVM and ICommands. I fixed the typos in your source code.

Comment: Thanks...,Its Working Fine.But My case,the file list is an ObservableCollection like ObservableCollection<Files> fileList;Where Files is a class which contains filename,status,size. I'm using this file list for uploading,While uploading the status will change,And need to reflect in the grid.These uploading are doing in Asynchronous way.

Comment: Can you post sample code how you are doing Asynchronous upload.. so that i can try to give you appropriate answer

Comment: Me solved it using multiple views with corresponding viewmodels...Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

Those XAML snippets just translate to

```
dataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("FileList"));
```

You need to keep track of how many clicks have occurred in a field, further you need to have a reference to the DataGrid of course. (You could create one via [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) and store that in the Button's `Tag` or `CommandParameter` if you use commands which would be more likely with MVVM i suppose)

Comment: Actually it is translated to var binding = new Binding(...); BindingOperations.SetBinding(dataGrid, ItemsControl.ItemsSource, binding);